# Can I make $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"); to a int value so that I can compare it to present date?

Tags: javascript, php

Example I have a date "2021-04-14 02:26:05am" and I want to select data that inserted after that date. Hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: You've to specify your database, it's not possible to answer the question without that information. Additionally, it would be nice, if we'd see the table and column names (and type) of the table you've stored the insertion date (that's usually not automatically included into tables).

Comment: @Teemu sorry my bad first time using stackoverflow ill consider doing that next time godbless

Comment: You could also edit this question, that way it would be more useful to future readers. Bob's answer is just a stab into dark, which happened to hit, but nobody really knows, which problem it actually resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use strotime("2021-04-14 02:26:05am")

Comment: Answered already I used "<" in my query